# Regex for NANP phone number with non-repeating last 7 digits

Tags: .net, regex, validation, phone-number

I have to validate a 10 digit (US) phone number in the NANP format (no special characters allowed) in .NET and also check to make sure the last 7 digits of the phone number are non-repeating. So far, I have written the following regex to validate the NANP format

```
^(?:[2-9][0-8][0-9])([2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4})$
```

How do I modify this regex to also account for non-repeating last 7 digits? Please note that using two regexes is not an option due to constraints of existing code.

Edit:
I have to check for consecutive duplicates in all 7 digits. For e.g. 2062222222 should be considered invalid whereas 2062221234 or 2062117777 should be considered valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about *consecutive* repeating digits, or do all seven digits have to be unique?  For example:

```
2342497553  // consecutive duplicates
2345816245  // non-consecutive duplicates
2345816249  // no duplicates
```

This regex filters out consecutive duplicates:

```
^(?:[2-9][0-8][0-9])(?!.*(\d)\1)([2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4})$
```

...while this one disallows *any* duplicate digits:

```
^(?:[2-9][0-8][0-9])(?!.*(\d).*\1)([2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4})$
```

After the first three digits have been consumed, the lookahead tries to find a character that's repeated, either immediately (`(?!.*(.)\1)`) or with optional intervening characters (`(?!.*(.).*\1)`).  And it's a *negative* lookahead, so if it succeeds, the overall match fails.

---

**EDIT:** It turns out the problem is simpler than I thought.  To filter out numbers like `2345555555`, where the last seven digits are identical, use this:

```
^(?:[2-9][0-8][0-9])(?!(\d)\1+$)([2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4})$
```

It's important to include the end anchor (`$`), because without that it would fail to match valid numbers like `2345555556`.  Alternatively, you could tell it to look for exactly six more of the captured digit: `(?!(\d)\1{6})`.

Comment: I am checking for consecutive duplicates in all 7 digits. For e.g. 2062222222 should be considered invalid whereas 2062221234 or 206 2117777 should be considered valid. Sorry, my question was not very clear. I will edit the question and add this information.

Comment: Thanks Alan! The regex in your edit solves the specific problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the non-repeating portion of this came up last night and the general consensus was that regular expressions can't handle non-repetition directly, you'd have to put in an unmanageably large number of alternative cases.  I don't think I've actually seen it proven, but I'm pretty sure it's true.  It boils down to the fact that regular expressions have no memory.  I suggest you use the regexp to validate the format and run it through a separate algorithm to check for repetition.